# How to get the default font details used by iOS to display UITableView header title?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am implementing `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` delegate in order to display text and icon for a grouped table view. I am using a `UILabel` for the text part and wish it to look exactly as titles appear when `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` is implemented.

I don't wish to use hard coded font names and font sizes in order to ensure that code will work on various iOS devices, and on various iOS versions. (especially future ones that might change these defaults).

Any ideas?

Comment: Afaik the section header title text ist a normal systemFontOfSize:13 with all text in upper case.

Comment: I think you will find that `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will override `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` or visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in another part of my app... maybe this will help you?

```
CGFloat preferredFontSize = [UIFont systemFontSize];
//  or instead of systemFontSize; else smallSystemFontSize, labelFontSize, buttonFontSize...
UIFont *preferredFontForList = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:preferredFontSize];
```

PS: I think you will find that `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will override `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` or visa versa.